# What does "Pandercetes" (genus of spiders) mean?

Tags: entomology, etymology, language

**"Pandercetes"** is a taxonomic genus, and refers to certain Huntsman spiders (found in Australia/Asia).
It was named by Koch, a German entomologist, in 1875.

What does the name itself mean or connote? What are the defining characteristics of this genus?
I could not get a clue as to what roots the word is made of .. pander + cetes? pan + dercetes? My understanding leads nowhere this far.

Comment: Koch did write a book describing these and other species:

Die Arachniden Australiens nach der Natur beschrieben und abgebildet By Koch, Ludwig, 1825-1908 Nürnberg :Verlag von Bauer & Raspe,1871-1890.

Harvard apparently has scanned volumes: https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/bibliography/121660

Perhaps the reasoning will be found there - should be fun hunt!

Comment: *Cetus* or *cete* means "whale" in Latin, and is the root of the English word "cetacean". Don't know how that refers to huntsman spiders, though...

Comment: biodiversitylibrary mentions highlight this genus' eyes "the eye area strongly raised in all directions" (as translated from Koch's German writings) .. and ..
Dercetes of Phyle is a character in Aristophanes' writings, whose name Dercetes itself means "looker", who ruins his eyes sobbing for his oxen.
Putting this together, I might conclude that Pandercetes can be broken into pan + dercetes, or "everywhere-looking" or simply "one with raised eye sockets in all directions"